# How to connect a pod to internet ? [K8S]

Tags: kubernetes

1. I installed Kubernetes "the kubeadm way"
2. I joined two nodes

When I run an nginx pod then try to curl [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) it fails.

```
$ kubectl exec -it nginx -- sh 
# curl http://google.com
'curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.com
```

How can I resolve this ?

- I disabled firewalld on master and worker nodes
- I am running K8S behind a corporate proxy
- I added the ip address of the Api server to NO_PROXY list ( on master and worker nodes)
- I added the ip address of the worker nodes to NO_PROXY list ( on the master node)

cni conf:

```
    "cniVersion": "0.3.1",
    "name": "crio",
    "type": "bridge",
    "bridge": "cni0",
    "isGateway": true,
    "ipMasq": true,
    "hairpinMode": true,
    "ipam": {
        "type": "host-local",
        "routes": [
            { "dst": "0.0.0.0/0" },
            { "dst": "1100:200::1/24" }
        ],
        "ranges": [
            [{ "subnet": "10.85.0.0/16" }],
            [{ "subnet": "1100:200::/24" }]
        ]
    }
}
```

When I run nginx container with podman then try to execute a curl within the container :
$ curl http://google.com (timeout)

Comment: coredns pods in kube-system namespace is running?

Comment: Yes they are running

Comment: Please take a look at [Debugging DNS Resolution](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/) and let me know if you have any unexpected behavior.

Comment: @mWatney kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup kubernetes.default
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

command terminated with exit code 1

Comment: Where are you deploying this cluster? Bare Metal, cloud, virtual machine? What CNI are you using? Which steps did you followed to create your cluster? I know you are using kubeadm, but how?

Comment: I have two phisical machines, I'am using cri-o as CRI                                                 cni :100-crio-bridge.conf,  I added the conf in the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Delete the cluster by running `kubeadm reset`
2. Delete `/opt/bni/bin/weave-*`.
3. Restart the machine before creating new cluster by `kubeadm init`.

Looking like the following issue:

https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/issues/2888

Comment: Actually, I have no such directory /opt/bni/bin/

Comment: Then you might not need to implement that step

Comment: Could you check if you're able to ping **10.128.242.90** or **216.58.208.110** from inside the pod. Ithese are one of the google's server. If you can ping this then this is a DNS issue.

Comment: Can't ping them !!